# Sending broadcast from App A to App B and back

Tags: android

Made two simple apps App A has one activity and one broadcast receiver. App B only has a broadcast receiver.

I'm sending a broadcast from A to B. Then I send a response back to A from B.

```
A -> B -> A
```

So this work very well. Then I tried to integrate the same stuff in app A in my actual app to communicate with B. And suddenly the response back from B doesn't work.

```
Actual app -> B -> Nothing
```

It seems that the broadcast receiver in my actual app is not able to register. Actual app manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.app.customer">

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.app.b" />
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:appCategory="productivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/appTheme.DayNight"
        tools:targetApi="o">

        <activity
            android:name=".home.SomeActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" /> 

        <receiver
            android:name="com.app.a.SomeReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.a.RESPONSE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Actual app BroadcastReceiver:

```
package com.app.a

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent

class SomeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        // Nothing is ever received here
    }
}
```

Broadcast made from app B:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, receiverIntent: Intent) {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = "com.app.a.RESPONSE"
    intent.putExtra("message", "Hello")
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES)
    intent.component = ComponentName("com.app.a", "com.app.a.SomeReceiver")
    context.sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

Any idea why SomeReceiver is not receiving the broadcast sent from App B? Is there anything which can block broadcast receivers?

Comment: have you tried to send this broadcast from an activity in app B?

Comment: No, but like I wrote it worked when I was using App A and B. When switching from A to my actual app it stopped working. So I don't think the problem is with App B as I haven't changed anything there.

Comment: Have you updated `ComponentName` to target `com.app.customer`?

Comment: Yes, its not that either.